# How to make a html code only display once a day?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to show a preview player but i am going to add a refresh code that refreshes the page in 5 minutes so they can only see the html code for 5 minutes so my question is how would i set it up to make a cookie so it will only show my HTML code one time PER day. If they refresh it will say "YOU USED YOUR PREVIEW FOR TODAY COME BACK TOMORROW" or something..... Here is what i have tried
Any help is greatly Appreciated i can use HTML or PHP it dont matter to me which :)

```
    <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Test dialog">
    MY HTML CODE HERE
    </div>
    </body>
    </script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
       // Make sure dialog is initially hidden:
       $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});
    
        // Check for the "whenToShowDialog" cookie, if not found then show the dialog and save the cookie.
        // The cookie will expire and every 2 days and the dialog will show again.
    
        if ($.cookie('whenToShowDialog') == null) {
    
            // Create expiring cookie, 1 days from now:
            $.cookie('whenToShowDialog', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    
            // Show dialog
            $('#dialog').dialog("open");        
        }
    
    });
    </script>
PREVIEW USED FOR TODAY COME baCK TOMORROW
```

Comment: You can try `setInterval` which is the easiest way

Comment: if client 1. delete cookie manually, 2. open browser in private mode, 3. create copy of your page without javascript code or inject own javascript, your check will fail. It is easy to avoid your checks for someone who little bit understand web technologies. All checks should be run at backend server based on client IP + cookies + all another possible tracking information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie that expires at the end of the day when a user visits the site.

```
document.cookie = `visited=true; expires=${dateObjectForEndOfDay}`;
```

Then, when a client visits the page you can read the cookie and see if it is set. Expired cookies won't display, so if the last cookie has expired it will be as if the user had never visited the site.
(The below code is pinched from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

const siteWasVisited = getCookie('visited');
```